# Vertical scroll not showing when height set to 100% in React app

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a React app where I always want the content to be at least 100% of height to color the background accordingly. I have tried achieving this with the following CSS 100% height at the top level which works. The issue is that when the content of the `root` exceeds 100% the scroll bar does not appear when the content exceeds the end of the page. Any ideas on how I can make the vertical scrollbar appear when having 100% height.

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

#root {
  height: 100%;
}
```

**Index**

```
<html>
  <body>        
    <div id="root"></div>            
  </body>
</html>
```

**App (content is being rendered in content)**

```
/* eslint-disable flowtype/require-valid-file-annotation */

import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import Toolbar from 'material-ui/Toolbar';
import List, { ListItem, ListItemIcon, ListItemText } from 'material-ui/List';
import logo_long from '../../assets/images/logo_long.png';

import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import Hidden from 'material-ui/Hidden';
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider';
import MenuIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Menu';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';

import Collapse from 'material-ui/transitions/Collapse';
import ExpandLess from 'material-ui-icons/ExpandLess';
import ExpandMore from 'material-ui-icons/ExpandMore';
import BusinessIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Business';
import EventIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Event';
import DashboardIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Dashboard';
import {
  Link,
  NavLink
} from 'react-router-dom';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    zIndex: 1,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  appFrame: {
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  appBar: {
    position: 'absolute',
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    },
  },
  navIconHide: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      display: 'none',
    },
  },
  drawerHeader: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  drawerPaper: {
    width: 250,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      width: drawerWidth,
      position: 'relative',
      height: '100%',
    }
  },
  nested: {
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 4,
  },
  content: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
    width: '100%',
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    height: 'calc(100% - 56px)',
    marginTop: 56,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      height: 'calc(100% - 64px)',
      marginTop: 64,
    },
  },
  subLink: {
    textDecoration: 'none'
  },
  text: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.A400,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  flex: {
    flex: 1,
  },

});

const CustomNavLink = (props) => (
  <NavLink  className={props.classes.subLink} to={{ pathname: props.to }}>
    <ListItem button className={props.classes.nested}>
      <ListItemText classes={props.pathname === props.to ? {text: props.classes.text} : null}
                    inset
                    primary={props.displayName} />
    </ListItem>
  </NavLink>
);

class ResponsiveDrawer extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      mobileOpen: false,
      adminOpen: true,
      jobsOpen: false,
      reportsOpen: false,
      activePath: "/admin"
    };
  }

  handleClick = state => {
    if(state === "admin") {
      this.setState({adminOpen: !this.state.adminOpen})
    } else if (state === "jobs") {
      this.setState({jobsOpen: !this.state.jobsOpen})
    } else if (state === "reports") {
      this.setState({reportsOpen: !this.state.reportsOpen})
    } else {
      console.log("unknown link group")
    }
  };

  handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    this.setState({ mobileOpen: !this.state.mobileOpen });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes, theme } = this.props;
    const drawer = (
      <div>
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
          {/*<img src={logo_long} style={{top:5}} />*/}
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <List className={classes.root}>
          <ListItem button onClick={() => this.handleClick("admin")}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <BusinessIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText inset primary="Admin" />
            {this.state.adminOpen ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
          </ListItem>
          <Collapse in={this.state.adminOpen} transitionDuration="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <CustomNavLink to="/admin/users"
                           classes={classes}
                           pathname={this.props.location.pathname}
                           displayName="Users" />
            <CustomNavLink to="/admin/companies"
                           classes={classes}
                           pathname={this.props.location.pathname}
                           displayName="Companies" />
            <CustomNavLink to="/admin/products"
                           classes={classes}
                           pathname={this.props.location.pathname}
                           displayName="Products" />
          </Collapse>
          <Link className={classes.subLink} to={{ pathname: "/jobs" }}>
            <ListItem button>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <EventIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText classes={this.props.location.pathname === "/jobs" ? {text: classes.text} : null} inset primary="Jobs" />
            </ListItem>
          </Link>
          <ListItem button onClick={() => this.handleClick("reports")}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <DashboardIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText inset primary="Reports" />
            {this.state.reportsOpen ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
          </ListItem>
          <Collapse in={this.state.reportsOpen} transitionDuration="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <CustomNavLink to="/reports"
                           classes={classes}
                           pathname={this.props.location.pathname}
                           displayName="Job Reports" />
            <CustomNavLink to="/reports/activity"
                           classes={classes}
                           pathname={this.props.location.pathname}
                           displayName="Activity Reports" />
          </Collapse>
        </List>
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <div className={classes.appFrame}>
          <AppBar className={classes.appBar}>
            <Toolbar>
              <IconButton
                color="contrast"
                aria-label="open drawer"
                onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle}
                className={classes.navIconHide}
              >
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Typography type="title" color="inherit" noWrap className={classes.flex}>
                {this.props.componentTitle}
              </Typography>
              {this.props.user ?
                <Button color="contrast" onClick={this.props.handleLogout}>Logout</Button>
                :
                <Button color="contrast" onClick={this.props.handleLogin}>Login</Button>
              }

            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
          <Hidden mdUp>
            <Drawer
              type="temporary"
              anchor={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'right' : 'left'}
              open={this.state.mobileOpen}
              classes={{
                paper: classes.drawerPaper,
              }}
              onRequestClose={this.handleDrawerToggle}
              ModalProps={{
                keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
              }}
            >
              {drawer}
            </Drawer>
          </Hidden>
          <Hidden mdDown implementation="css">
            <Drawer
              type="permanent"
              open
              classes={{
                paper: classes.drawerPaper,
              }}
            >
              {drawer}
            </Drawer>
          </Hidden>
          <main className={classes.content}>
            <Typography type="body1" noWrap>
            </Typography>
            {this.props.children}
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ResponsiveDrawer.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(ResponsiveDrawer);
```

Comment: "want the content to be at least 100% of height" There is a css property for that. It is called `min-height`

Answer (score 2):

You have `overflow: hidden;` set for root element which will cause that behaviour. Add

```
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Comment: Thanks! When I remove `overflow: hidden` the element exceeds 100% width. Applying max-width of 100% doesn't seem to help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For the component you want to enable scroll, use this style

```
style={{ overflowY: 'scroll', height: 'calc(100vh - 127px)' }}
```

Specific height value is mandatory here.

If you have a scroll enabled for root element or body (which is default), two scrolls will be visible in that case. So, you might have to remove the scroll there. For that you can use hooks (if functional component)

```
import { useLayoutEffect } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () =? {
  useLockBodyScroll();

  /-----rest of the code  
}

const useLockBodyScroll = () => {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const originalOverflowStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.body).overflow;
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';

    // This will set back the root/body overflow to Scroll when the component is unmounted
    return () => document.body.style.overflow = originalOverflowStyle;
  }, []);
}
```

useLayoutEffect() is react Hooks API like useState()